# Writing image to local server

Tags: node.js, http-get

**Update**

The accepted answer was good for last year but today I would use the package everyone else uses:
https://github.com/mikeal/request

---

**Original**

I'm trying to grab google's logo and save it to my server with node.js.

This is what I have right now and doesn't work:

```
        var options = {
            host: 'google.com',
            port: 80,
            path: '/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'
        };

        var request = http.get(options);

        request.on('response', function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                fs.writeFile(dir+'image.png', chunk, function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('It\'s saved!');
                });
            });
        });
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A few things happening here:

1. I assume you required fs/http, and set the dir variable :)
2. google.com redirects to www.google.com, so you're saving the redirect response's body, not the image
3. the response is streamed. that means the 'data' event fires many times, not once. you have to save and join all the chunks together to get the full response body
4. since you're getting binary data, you have to set the encoding accordingly on response and writeFile (default is utf8)

This should work:

```
var http = require('http')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , options

options = {
    host: 'www.google.com'
  , port: 80
  , path: '/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'
}

var request = http.get(options, function(res){
    var imagedata = ''
    res.setEncoding('binary')

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imagedata += chunk
    })

    res.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile('logo.png', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: how come you don't use semi-colons?

Comment: @jcdavid http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Comment: this is terrible advice. never do `.setEncoding('binary')` and use `res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream())` instead of buffering the entire image in memory. you can use this library if you're too lazy: https://github.com/stream-utils/save-to

Comment: @JonathanOng 2011, IIRC setting the encoding was required at the time. Agreed on streams, feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: This is only working for Google Logo image. How can I use above code to save this image https://eteacher.me/assets/images/eteacher.png

Comment: Semicolons are not required in javascript. Also this is a standard: https://standardjs.com/

Comment: @MartinMuzatko "a" standard, not "the" standard. Just because some opinionated developers decided to *call* their semicolon aesthetic 'standard' doesn't mean it *is* a standard. Besides, TC39 warn against relying on ASI these days.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye this is true. The authors of ES also said that it is not really smart to rely on ASI. I am right now a bit torn between requiring a good knowledge about how ASI works and therefore avoid a few situations, or just use semicolons everywhere. To be honest, I like using fewer characters - it looks a bit cleaner. Nevertheless, people should know when semicolons are required either way, because I see developers adding semicolons everywhere.. After block definitions (functions, if, else, etc)

Comment: And that's when you reach for `prettier` and stop thinking about "what styleguide to follow", knowing that it will put them in (or not) in a way that is syntactically correct as far as the spec is concerned.

Answer (score 40):

This thread is old but I wanted to do same things with the https://github.com/mikeal/request  package.

Here a working example

```
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
// Or with cookies
// var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});

request.get({url: 'https://someurl/somefile.torrent', encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, response, body) {
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.torrent", body, 'binary', function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("The file was saved!");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: The docs now say to set the encoding to null for binary or else it is considered utf8:https://github.com/request/request "encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)"

Comment: I confirm, you should now set `{ encoding: null }`

Answer (score 27):

I suggest you use [http-request](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/http-request), so that even redirects are managed.

```
var http = require('http-request');
var options = {url: 'http://localhost/foo.pdf'};
http.get(options, '/path/to/foo.pdf', function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log('File downloaded at: ' + result.file);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have to admit, this is about as straight forward as an http download can get.

Comment: Apparently http-get has reached its end of life, and the successor is http-request.

Comment: Indeed, and it seems totally retro-compatible.

Comment: that's a good solution, but consider that `http-request` in some cases like node web kit `nwjs` requires native modules (C static libraries), then you have to compile against the architecture if deploying it somewhere else than server environment.

Answer (score 6):

**How about this?**

```
var http = require('http'), 
fs = require('fs'), 
options;

options = {
    host: 'www.google.com' , 
    port: 80,
    path: '/images/logos/ps_logo2.png'
}

var request = http.get(options, function(res){

//var imagedata = ''
//res.setEncoding('binary')

var chunks = [];

res.on('data', function(chunk){

    //imagedata += chunk
    chunks.push(chunk)

})

res.on('end', function(){

    //fs.writeFile('logo.png', imagedata, 'binary', function(err){

    var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
    fs.writeFile('logo.png', buffer, function(err){
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('File saved.')
    })

})
```

Comment: What if the URL is incorrect? I was saving <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>

Comment: @yuquin, How to use the code to save this image eteacher.me/assets/images/eteacher.png

Comment: It is Really cool ! Thank you very much. And I wonder why cannot use string doing similar operation.

Answer (score 3):

**Cleanest** way of saving image locally using [request](https://github.com/request/request):

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://link/to/your/image/file.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('fileName.png'))
```

If you need to **add authentication token** in headers do this:

```
const request = require('request');
request({
        url: 'http://link/to/your/image/file.png',
        headers: {
            "X-Token-Auth": TOKEN,
        }
    }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filename.png'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution using `fs.readFileSync(./my_local_image_path.jpg)`

This is for reading images from [Azure Cognative Services's Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/node-analyze)

```
const subscriptionKey = 'your_azure_subscrition_key';
const uriBase = // **MUST change your location (mine is 'eastus')**
    'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/analyze';

// Request parameters.
const params = {
    'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Description,Adult,Faces',
    'maxCandidates': '2',
    'details': 'Celebrities,Landmarks',
    'language': 'en'
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,
    body: fs.readFileSync(./my_local_image_path.jpg),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
if (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return;
}
let jsonString = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');
body = JSON.parse(body);
if (body.code) // err
{
    console.log("AZURE: " + body.message)
}

console.log('Response\n' + jsonString);
```