# nodejs Lambda with S3 upload via API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been trying to get a simple serverless API Gateway -> NodeJS Lambda -> S3 working however it appears that the Lambda just uploads corrupt files.

This code would download the file from a URL then straight upload to S3.
I've tried both putObject & upload (with the different params) with no success. Looking at the file sizes when I download the original is is 24KB and the downloaded (corrupt) image from S3 is 44KB.

I simply test the application by doing a POST to the API Gateway URL.

Any ideas?

```
var url =
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg/500px-AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg.png"
module.exports.upload = function(event, context, callback) {
  https.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = ""
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
      // Agregates chunks
      body += chunk
    })
    res.on("end", function() {
      console.log(body)

      // Once you received all chunks, send to S3 - putObject only
      var params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: "aws-logo.png",
        Body: body
      }

      var s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: "aws-logo-upload.png",
        Body: body,
        ContentType: "image/png"
      }

      s3.upload(s3Params, function(err, data) {
        // s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("error")
          console.error(err, err.stack)
          callback(null, { statusCode: 404, error })
        } else {
          console.log("ok")
          console.log(data)
          let response = {
            statusCode: 200
          }
          callback(null, response)
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Probably the the request execute twice. did you bind your lambda function to any events ?

Comment: It is tied via my serverless.yml: functions:
  upload:
    handler: handler.upload
    events:
      - http:
          path: event/upload
          method: post

Comment: Does your code work outside of API Gateway/Lambda?

Comment: It does not work when I try to manually test/run it in the AWS Console.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836438/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-with-http-request

Comment: I did try with different binary encoding settings - along with when I was using API gateway to actually trigger it with image data in the HTTP Body with the same problem (this is my simplified code to locate the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me outside of API Gateway/Lambda. It yields a PNG in S3 that's downloadable as a valid 23.7 KB image. I'd expect the equivalent to work in Lambda.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const logourl =
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg/500px-AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg.png';

const getThenUpload = (url, callback) => {
  https.get(url, (res) => {
    const data = [];

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: 'aws-logo-upload.png',
        Body: Buffer.concat(data),
        ContentType: 'image/png',
      };

      s3.upload(params, (err, rsp) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err, err.stack);
          callback(err, { statusCode: 404, err });
        } else {
          console.log(rsp);
          callback(null, { statusCode: 200 });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

getThenUpload(logourl, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you POSTing via API Gateway? The actual file contents, a URL pointing to the file, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for this :) worked! Had to change some of my API Gateway integration's. That way I could pass the raw data as Base64.