# Node Server and base64

Tags: node.js, base64

I am having some issues converting a payload received (`req.body`) to a correctly formatted base64 string.

The payload is received and looks like the below example. I know that it's encrypted coming in but I'm wondering if there is anything that could be happening node server side that makes it look like this, it seems malformed and not how it should be

```
 body: '&R۽5�l|L�\u001b�\u0014햱����\u00020#��[cV[AD&P�\u0001��˯���\n' +
`#B軉�6Y¤�\u0010�l�\u0012"D�dʦ�nb�g���\u0017����߉�{�a\u000e�:��\u0014\u0005�4\u0018!��u\u001e��s!վ]�\u0011KɆ�<!\u001d��#a�Ӿǥ+\f�iWEź�����:^�Վߎ�NP�M�G�_x�}�b1W�t�\u000f?*�2N�s��\u0000\u0015\u001e��o��� |y.\u0004n�e��64z�eu3\u0007(��j�R�\u0001 jzO\u0012�IF\u0002��w_����%�\u001b\u0010��\u0010��5�\u0016�.1�\u0006�\f\u0014�$�|\u000e�E�5�����o�MΆA\u001a��\u0010���׽���-ܹ��\u0003�jV�0b\u0002�\u001f��\\^"\\���\u0000��%�̓B�TfI��3��2U���[@�ۍ�'bT�]�\u0007�������\u0016 �P��x?\u0014�ly*8\u00134�NR����<��\u0012^�"#�V���!\u0010=�\u0006�"r�c�a�/L���vq�<\u0015�\u0006H��\u0014�\u001f�m�~�Ֆ�\u0011>L+����Yw���٘�\u0007ur�&�i�B4\n` +
```

If I convert the payload to a base64 string then i get something like this (the + and / characters do not seem right)

```
var encryptedBytes = Buffer.from(req.body);
var encryptedStr = encryptedBytes.toString('base64');
console.log({encryptedStr});

{ encryptedStr: 'JlLbvTXvv71sfEzvv70b77+9fxTtlrHvv73vv73vv73vv70CMCPvv73vv71bY1ZbQUQmUO+/vQHvv73vv73Lr++/ve+/ve+/vQojQui7ie+/vTZZwqTvv70Q77+9bO+/vRIiRO+/vWTKpu+/vW5i77+9Z++/ve+/ve+/vRfvv73vv73vv73vv73fie+/vXvvv71hDu+/vTrvv73vv70UBe+/vTQYIe+/ve+/vXUe77+977+9cyHVvl3vv70RS8mG77+'}
```

If I compare this to a base64 string I grab from the request on an iOS device for example, these seem rather different, plus this base64 string below can be decrypted successfully, which implies the issue could be within node?

```
{ base64data: 'ZGRIUUJhR0dMc3BTVFdQSHppS3BZUDY1UmJWSkFmbnRpekg1a29nUnlFMGtZemExU0RwS1h0VHlNd1lHMnhRcEZiMjEzNEwwYXduNllHR1p0aU1HM3YzcWlyTnlSd2RWSmNHQldMRVVMWklWaGRpNzBNWHVPNkZaSnJBUWZ6YnBJbERESzBiTEpoUGVCS3ZiU1d2NnRIcktIb'}
```

So my question here, is there something i need to do node server side to correctly parse or translate the `req.body` ready to be converted into a base64 string?

Comment: Are you sure that request body is properly encoded (is there any information on how)? Seeing that UTF-8 replacement character in there makes me wonder if the issue isn't that the server sends malformed data in the first place.

Comment: `'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'`, so could that have anything to do with it? @m90

Comment: Looks like you're receiving binary data in your response body which is very hard / impossible to represent as an utf-8 string, so you might need to read it into a buffer directly. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024737/797194