# require filename while downloading file using request module nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

**I am using request module in nodejs to download a file(only image file) using this,**

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png')),
```

or say

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)),
```

but I have only url available and I have required to save the file with its actual name,
So I have required to found filename from the given url,

**please suggest me method which donot extracted last part of url**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js Writing image to local server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294470/node-js-writing-image-to-local-server)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

// ...

var filename = path.basename(url);

request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));
```

Comment: no mscdex, I have not required this, I know this extract the last part of url and my URL is somewhat different, consist of file key and Token like http://beta.business.applane.com/rest/file/download?token=5437bdb1811dfb0f03ec49a3&filekey=541bc4c909e41ce549567c07, which gives below file name download?token=5437bdb1811dfb0f03ec49a3&filekey=541bc4c909e41ce549567c07, but actually its filename is photo.jpg, is there any way to get this...

Comment: Well, in that case, check your `Content-Disposition` header value. If it has a `filename` parameter in it, then you need to extract that. FWIW [this function](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/3a24ac52aa02433f0f44b2a5954fd4e3e3ee3079/lib/utils.js#L7-L91) is what the `busboy` module uses to parse those kinds of header values.

Comment: I am not getting Content-Disposition in response.headers

Comment: Then where is `photo.jpg` coming from in the response?