# How to write an image in Node after request() has returned

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

This feels like an obvious question but it's perplexing me: I want a Node function that downloads a resource at a URI. I need it to work for several different content types without the user needing to specify which type it is.

I know how to pipe `request` to `fs.createWriteStream` when you know it's going to be an image, but not how to handle it when you've already invoked the callback from request. Here's where I am:

```
var request = require('request'),
    fs = require('graceful-fs');

function cacheURI(uri, cache_path, cb) {
    request(uri, function(err, resp, body) {
        var content_type = resp.headers['content-type'].toLowerCase().split("; ")[0],
            type = content_type.split("/")[0],
            sub_type = content_type.split("/")[1];

        if (sub_type == "json") {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        }

        if (type == "image") {
            // this is where the trouble starts
            var ws = fs.createWriteStream(cache_path);
            ws.write(body);
            ws.on('close', function() {
                console.log('image done');
                console.log(resp.socket.bytesRead);
                ws.end();
                cb()
            });         
        } else {
            // this works fine for text resources
            fs.writeFile(cache_path, body, cb);     
        }


    });
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294470/node-js-writing-image-to-local-server/20490629#20490629) to a previous question suggests the following:

```
request.get({url: 'https://someurl/somefile.torrent', encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, response, body) {
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.torrent", body, 'binary', function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("The file was saved!");
  }); 
});
```

But I can't pass "binary" to `request` if I don't yet know the type of response I'll get.

**UPDATE**

Per the suggested answer, changing "close" to "finish" in the event handler does fire the callback:

```
        if (opts.image) {
            var ws = fs.createWriteStream(opts.path);
            ws.on('finish', function() {
                console.log('image done');
                console.log(resp.socket.bytesRead);
            });
            //tried as buffer as well
            //ws.write(new Buffer(body));
            ws.write(body);
            ws.end();
        }
```

This does write the image file, but not correctly:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is happening on your sever when "image" section runs?

Comment: Certainly-- the "close" callback never fires. Also tried "fs.writeFile" with "binary" option, no luck. (See update to Q). Thx!

Comment: try defining `ws.on('close')` before writing the data

Comment: Already did, no luck!

Comment: I am not sure if writeStream emits the "close" event. May want to check that... http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [here](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html), try using the `finish` event (if you have node >= v0.10)

```
ws.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('image done');
    console.log(resp.socket.bytesRead);
    ws.end();
    cb()
});
```

Comment: Thanks-this does successfully fire the callback, but the image it writes is note readable -- will post with screenshot.

Comment: Just added screenshot -- it's not a valid image file. Tried writing buffer too.