# Save a binary stream as an image file using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

Our LDAP server returns the thumbnail in the following binary format. How can I save the stream as an image on the computer using NodeJS?

[image: The received binary stream]

I tried the following solution, but the saved file *thumbnail.jpeg* cannot be opened as an image:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('thumbnail.jpeg', {my binary stream}, 'binary',
  function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File saved.')     
  })
```

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294470/node-js-writing-image-to-local-server the answer by Drasill should get you there the fastest.

Comment: looks like you've converted the binary data to utf8 string and saving it. Try saving the original buffer data.

Comment: @hassansin Thanks! You are right. I got the the original buffer data and it works :-)

Comment: @GChen can you post an update on what exactly you did ? I'm also stopped at this point.

Comment: @Harshad see https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/issues/137